# how to pass argument in sql query

Tags: sql-server

how to pass argument in sql query

ExecuteQuery("Delete from emp where empno = **auguement**);

Comment: please explain your question in detailed.with questions like this no one will able to the answer.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Can you give an example or explain what you want to do in more detail?

Comment: Yep, useful things like what programming language and what database.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to post more informaton but as a starter....

```
-- Passing a parameter for a Where clause in a SQL query

Declare @UserId int
Set @UserId = 12

Select * From dbo.Users
Where UserId = @UserId


-- Passing a parameter for use in a Stored Procedure

Declare @UserId int
Set @UserId = 12

Execute dbo.usp_Fetch_User_ById @UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to use the executeQuery Method (SQLServerStatement): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378540(SQL.90).aspx

then you jyst use regular string concatenation to build your query string.  However you should do a google search on "SQL INJECTION".

Answer (score 0):

To pass a parameter you need first to have a stored procedure that will consume the parameters:

```
create procedure sp_AddNumbers
(@int1 int,
@in2 int)
as

  select @in1 + @int2

go
```

after that call it with code such as

```
exec sp_Addnumbers @int1=3, @int2=9
```

or

```
exec sp_Addnumbers 3, 9
```